# Using Ajax .load function from an admin page of wordpress results in 404 from assets in plugin folder

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress plugin and on the admin page of said plugin they fill out a form. I am using Ajax to check the ID of their entry against my DB  using .load() which is resulting in a 404. I can print the file using the same file path.

I have tested the file path and "require_once(plugin_dir_path( **FILE** ).'assets/test.php');" prints out the file just fine. Since "wordpress", "404" & "plugin" are pretty heavy keywords its been hard to find someone with a similar issue from google.

```
//php on admin page
 $loadURL = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'assets/test.php';

 <button id="button">Load</button>
 <div id="div1"></div>

// js (also on admin page)
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#button").click(function(){
       $("#div1").load("<?php echo $loadURL; ?>");
         console.log( "Load was performed." );
     });
   });
 })(jQuery);
```

The result is a 404 upon clicking the button. Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I'm really dumb... I needed to use plugin_dir_url( **FILE** ) and not plugin_dir_path( **FILE** )